# Sending function sent data to php file by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to a database.php file by ajax. My Index file has a form which will collect a 4 digit input then sends to a js function which sends the data to my db file. At the moment the Db file is being called because I get a result in the console but the 4 digit key is not being sent. I expect I have done something wrong with the ajax script.

Any help please

```js
function addCode(key) {
  var code = document.forms[0].code;
  if (code.value.length < 4) {
    code.value = code.value + key;
  }
  if (code.value.length == 4) {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(alarm, 1000, code.value);
  }
}

function alarm(code) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "alarm.php",
    data: code,
    cache: false,
    success: function(responseText) {
      console.log(responseText) // show returned text in console
    }
  })
  emptyCode();
}

function emptyCode() {
  document.forms[0].code.value = "";
}
```

Comment: you should try what you are getting in code. then assign it to data by key and value.

Comment: when you want data at database.php why are you using alarm.php in ajax callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're just sending the value by itself with no key. To fix this you could provide `data` with an object that will be form encoded when the request is sent:

```
data: { code: code },
```

Then in your PHP code you can retrieve the posted value by its key:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
```

Comment: Thanks the data: { code: code } worked fine, I already had the other part set up. Now working all ok